# Phonegap and bootastrap template like a AdminLTE

Tags: cordova, angular-ui-bootstrap

It's possible? I try to run it in the phonegap emulator app and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this one it is free

https://w3layouts.com/augment-an-admin-panel-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the problem is with Nmap and ngRoute, when I try to use, the screen fails to appear.